# Double click, how handle it?

Tags: c++, glfw

I was trying to find out how handle double click with left(or any) mouse button.
But I can't find any information about it.

Can anybody help me? I don't want to write my own double click handler.

GLFW_REPEAT doesn't work with mouse buttons.

Comment: why? there's nothing wrong in my code, I want to know if there is any way to handle double click using GLFW3, without writing my own code to handle double click, because there are 3 actions states for keyboard events, but for mouse only 2, GLFW_PRESS and GLFW_RELASE, and GLFW_REPEAT is only for keyboard -.-

Comment: I remember reading somewhere it was in the roadmap for future GLFW features, let me see if I can find that source.

Comment: @pwny It's right here: http://wiki.glfw.org/wiki/Suggestions_and_ideas#Double-click_support Odd how OP says he can't find any information on it, when that was the first result in google for me.

Comment: @remyabel beat me to it by approximately 15 seconds :)

Comment: Which platform?  What windowing framework?

Answer (score 4):

What's so wrong about writing your own double click handler?

Just save the time the mouse click happens, e.g. with `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()`, and when the next mouse click happens, compare the times. If it is under a specific value, a double click happened.

Comment: The problem with this is that you no longer respect the system settings for double clicking.  If a user has set their double click speed to "very slow" because they have a disability, well, you just excluded them from using your app.

Stuff like this is in the system APIs for a reason - there are tons of little ways to mess up your own double click handler even ignoring the system settings.  What if the user double clicks but holds down on the second one, then drags their mouse out of the hitbox?  Do you want to implement the handler for that?

Comment: GLFW has no definitive support so unless OP wants to switch libraries, a primitive implementation will have to do.

Comment: In addition to Mason's comments, a proper handler should also detect how far the mouse has moved between the first and second click so that if the user clicks two different things in quick succession the second one isn't counted as a double click. FWIW SDL's SDL_MouseMoveEvent has a "clicks" property which handles this correctly and accounts for both the OS setting (on Windows, via the Win32 API's GetDoubleClickTime function), and distance between clicks. 10 years later, glfw still doesn't support double clicking. :/