# A cross-platform way to detect Operational System double-click min interval with C++

Tags: c++, operating-system, mouse, double-click, multiplatform

My application is targeted to Windows, Linux and Mac OSX. Currently, I have an implementation of double-clicking that uses a hard-coded threshold of time between clicks to differentiate between single and double clicks (I don't use any GUI libraries, since the application precisely relies on my custom GUI implementation).

However, the application is almost ready for shipment and I would like to have a more proper implementation of double-clicking. By that, I mean one that reads the double-clicking minimum time interval currently being used by he user in her operational system, instead of arbitrarily defining such an interval. For me, the relevance of that should be obvious, but if not, I am thinking about avoiding problems that are, for instance, mentioned in the comments to the answer to this question: [Double click, how handle it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408343/double-click-how-handle-it)

The problem here sums up to this: how to read the operational-system double-clicking min interval in a cross platform application written in C++ and that does not use GUI libraries? Is there a way to read such a system-level information that works for Windows, Linux and OS-X?

I am surprised that it's so hard to find information on that, considering that one could suppose that it's such a fundamental, basic, thing to have in any application (although there seems to discussions on the difficulties to achieve that, e.g. this one int the [GLFW's feature-suggestion forums](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/462))

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Reading system-level settings is system-dependent by nature, but it's very rare that applications need to care about this particular setting - the window system (or your application framework, if you're using one) usually sends a double-click event when the user double-clicks.

Comment: _"one could suppose that it's such a fundamental, basic, thing to have in any application"_ Really? This entire goal seems extraordinarily weird to me.

Comment: Each GUI toolkit has its own setting. If this is of such paramount importance, the path of least resistance would be to use a cross-platform GUI toolkit such as Qt, and have only one config setting to worry about.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Good point, that made me realize that an edit to the question was needed. I am precisely looking for such a thing because I coded the whole GUI myself, without using any frameworks. That's the very reason I am asking how to get that information

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Could you please elaborate on why would it be extraordinarily weird? If one is a) not using a GUI library and b) coding in C++ a cross-platform application, how would the problem be unimportant? See the links in the edited version of my question.

Comment: Because you should be (a) using a GUI library, and (b) coding in C++ a cross-platform application. You decided not to do either of these things, but now you want to do cross-platform GUI-related things. How is that not weird?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Where did you read that I am not coding in C++ a cross-platform application, if that is exactly what I said in the question that is what *I am* doing? As for not using a GUI library, I didn't know one isn't allowed to be interested in a custom-tailored GUI aimed at specific usages without that being weird. Say that, for instance, to game developers.